# I'm getting error with CustomGridView in AlertDialog

Tags: java, android, gridview, layout, android-alertdialog

I have to create an AlertDialog for the user choose a category in the gridview, however I'm getting error. This is my code. When I click in the TextView to call the method that work in show dialog, the app crash. Anyone know some tutorial?

**category_grid.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/category_grid"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:columnWidth="90dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
    android:numColumns="2"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    android:verticalSpacing="10dp" >

</GridView>
```

**grid_single.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="@color/vermelho_row" >

<ImageView 
    android:id="@+id/category_image"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_action_image_photo_camera"
    android:layout_gravity="center"/>

<TextView 
    android:id="@+id/category_name"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="Experimentar"
    android:background="@color/laranja_row"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"/>


</LinearLayout>
```

**BaseAdapter**

```
package com.fb.newcomersapp;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class CustomGrid extends BaseAdapter{
private Context context;
private String [] categoryName;
private int [] categoryImage;
public CustomGrid(Context context, String [] categoryName, int [] categoryImage){
     this.context = context;
     this.categoryName = categoryName;
     this.categoryImage = categoryImage;
 }

 @Override
 public int getCount() {
     // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}

 @Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    View grid;
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)    context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
     if(convertView == null){
         grid = new View(context);
         grid = inflater.inflate(R.layout.grid_single, null);
        TextView textView = (TextView) grid.findViewById(R.id.category_name);
         ImageView imageView = (ImageView) grid.findViewById(R.id.category_image);
        textView.setText(categoryName[position]);
        imageView.setImageResource(categoryImage[position]);
    }
    else{
        grid = (View) convertView;
    }
    return grid;
    }

}
```

**Method in Activity to show dialog**

```
private void showAlertDialog() {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    CustomGrid adapter = new CustomGrid(NewEventActivity.this, categoryName, categoryImage);
    GridView grid = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.category_grid);


    grid.setAdapter(adapter);


    builder.setView(grid);
    builder.setTitle("Goto");
    builder.show();
}
```

** Log **

```
01-04 23:44:38.727: E/AndroidRuntime(10444): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-04 23:44:38.727: E/AndroidRuntime(10444): Process: com.fb.newcomersapp, PID: 10444
01-04 23:44:38.727: E/AndroidRuntime(10444): java.lang.NullPointerException
01-04 23:44:38.727: E/AndroidRuntime(10444):    at   com.fb.newcomersapp.NewEventActivity.showAlertDialog(NewEventActivity.java:205)
01-04 23:44:38.727: E/AndroidRuntime(10444):    at  com.fb.newcomersapp.NewEventActivity.access$6(NewEventActivity.java:199)
01-04 23:44:38.727: E/AndroidRuntime(10444):    at com.fb.newcomersapp.NewEventActivity$8.onClick(NewEventActivity.java:190)
01-04 23:44:38.727: E/AndroidRuntime(10444):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4456)
01-04 23:44:38.727: E/AndroidRuntime(10444):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18465)
01-04 23:44:38.727: E/AndroidRuntime(10444):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
01-04 23:44:38.727: E/AndroidRuntime(10444):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
01-04 23:44:38.727: E/AndroidRuntime(10444):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
01-04 23:44:38.727: E/AndroidRuntime(10444):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5086)
01-04 23:44:38.727: E/AndroidRuntime(10444):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-04 23:44:38.727: E/AndroidRuntime(10444):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
01-04 23:44:38.727: E/AndroidRuntime(10444):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
01-04 23:44:38.727: E/AndroidRuntime(10444):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
01-04 23:44:38.727: E/AndroidRuntime(10444):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: where is error? Please add stack trace of error.

Comment: What is line 205? GridView propably is null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you post your logcat it'll be easier to help you.

But I am guessing you are getting a NullPointerException on the line

```
grid.setAdapter(adapter);
```

When you call

```
GridView grid = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.category_grid);
```

You are going to get null
(Unless their is a category_grid in your current layout)
I think instead what you want to do is inflate the grid layout.

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
GridView grid = inflater.inflate(R.layout.category_grid, null);
```

Comment: I updated the post. I made the changes, the app did not crash, but the grid view didnt appear.

    private void showAlertDialog() {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    CustomGrid adapter = new CustomGrid(NewEventActivity.this, categoryName, categoryImage);
  
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    GridView grid = (GridView) inflater.inflate(R.layout.pick_category,  (ViewGroup)findViewById(R.id.category_grid));

  grid.setAdapter(adapter);
        
  builder.setView(grid);
  builder.show();
    }

Comment: That's good to hear. You might get better results by posting another question.
But for starters I can see that the method public int getCount() in your adapter always returns 0. I have no idea what categoryName is but getCount should probably return categoryName.length

Comment: I never thought this method influence on anything, just did what you told me and it worked. Why?

Comment: You'll probably find the best answer here http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html#getCount%28%29
If the view knows it has items then it will call getView to load items until the view is full or until you are out of items. Overall getCount should return the amount of items you want to show in your grid or whatever the adapter is used for (list/grid/etc).